# How does the pandas Compare function work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

Can someone explain the detailed implementation of the Pandas Compare() function that compares two dataframes?

Code Implementation:

```
def compare(
        self,
        other,
        align_axis: Axis = 1,
        keep_shape: bool_t = False,
        keep_equal: bool_t = False,
    ):
        from pandas.core.reshape.concat import concat

        if type(self) is not type(other):
            cls_self, cls_other = type(self).__name__, type(other).__name__
            raise TypeError(
                f"can only compare '{cls_self}' (not '{cls_other}') with '{cls_self}'"
            )

        mask = ~((self == other) | (self.isna() & other.isna()))
        keys = ["self", "other"]

        if not keep_equal:
            self = self.where(mask)
            other = other.where(mask)

        if not keep_shape:
            if isinstance(self, ABCDataFrame):
                cmask = mask.any()
                rmask = mask.any(axis=1)
                self = self.loc[rmask, cmask]
                other = other.loc[rmask, cmask]
            else:
                self = self[mask]
                other = other[mask]

        if align_axis in (1, "columns"):  # This is needed for Series
            axis = 1
        else:
            axis = self._get_axis_number(align_axis)

        diff = concat([self, other], axis=axis, keys=keys)

        if axis >= self.ndim:
            # No need to reorganize data if stacking on new axis
            # This currently applies for stacking two Series on columns
            return diff

        ax = diff._get_axis(axis)
        ax_names = np.array(ax.names)

        # set index names to positions to avoid confusion
        ax.names = np.arange(len(ax_names))

        # bring self-other to inner level
        order = list(range(1, ax.nlevels)) + [0]
        if isinstance(diff, ABCDataFrame):
            diff = diff.reorder_levels(order, axis=axis)
        else:
            diff = diff.reorder_levels(order)

        # restore the index names in order
        diff._get_axis(axis=axis).names = ax_names[order]

        # reorder axis to keep things organized
        indices = (
            np.arange(diff.shape[axis]).reshape([2, diff.shape[axis] // 2]).T.flatten()
        )
        diff = diff.take(indices, axis=axis)

        return diff
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's literally the pandas compare function?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) yet, I'd start there.

To hopefully shed some light on the high-level use, we can use some examples.

## e.g. 1 -- All the same

```py
import numpy as np  # 1.23.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

np.random.seed(0)

s0 = pd.Series(np.random.random(size=(5)))
s1 = s0.copy()

print(s0.compare(s1))
```

Out:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [self, other]
Index: []
```

Per the docs, the `.compare` method should only return rows that are ***not*** equal in `self` (i.e. `s0`) and `other` (i.e. `s1`). In the above, `s1` is an exact copy of `s0`. And therefore all rows should be exactly equal. Hence the return of an empty `DataFrame`.

## e.g. 2 -- A difference

```py
import numpy as np  # 1.23.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

np.random.seed(0)

s0 = pd.Series(np.random.random(size=(5)))
s1 = s0.copy()

# change the 0th element in `s1` to something else
s1.iloc[0] = "a different value"

print(s0.compare(s1))
```

Out:

```
       self              other
0  0.548814  a different value
```

We can see the standard usage of `.compare` by changing a single element in `s1`. The resulting frame will have two columns (`"self"` and `"other"`). The value in the 0th row in `s0` was some float, and the different value in `s1` is a string. Clearly different, as is shown by the results.

## e.g. 2 -- `keep_shape=True`

```py
import numpy as np  # 1.23.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

np.random.seed(0)

s0 = pd.Series(np.random.random(size=(5)))
s1 = s0.copy()

# change the 0th element in `s1` to something else
s1.iloc[0] = "a different value"

print(s0.compare(s1, keep_shape=True))
```

Out:

```
       self              other
0  0.548814  a different value
1       NaN                NaN
2       NaN                NaN
3       NaN                NaN
4       NaN                NaN
```

The docs for the `keep_shape` parameter say:

> ```
> keep_shape : bool, default False
>     If true, all rows and columns are kept.
>     Otherwise, only the ones with different values are kept.
> ```

Because we changed the argument from the default value of `False` to `True`, `.compare` will return a `DataFrame` with the same number of rows as `s0` and `s1`. The logic for this parameter can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/91111fd99898d9dcaa6bf6bedb662db4108da6e6/pandas/core/generic.py#L9222).

## e.g. 3 -- `keep_equal=True`

```py
import numpy as np  # 1.23.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

np.random.seed(0)

s0 = pd.Series(np.random.random(size=(5)))
s1 = s0.copy()

# change the 0th element in `s1` to something else
s1.iloc[0] = "a different value"

print(s0.compare(s1, keep_equal=True))
```

Out:

```
       self              other
0  0.548814  a different value
```

The docs for the `keep_equal` parameter say:

> ```
> keep_equal : bool, default False
>     If true, the result keeps values that are equal.
>     Otherwise, equal values are shown as NaNs.
> ```

Based on that, you may think the result should be limited to rows where `s0` and `s1` are the same. But that's not what happens. Why? The logic for this parameter is fairly short and can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/91111fd99898d9dcaa6bf6bedb662db4108da6e6/pandas/core/generic.py#L9218). If `keep_equal` is set to `True`, the conditional will be skipped and `self` and `other` will not have a `mask` applied.

But! Further down [in the `keep_shape` conditional](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/91111fd99898d9dcaa6bf6bedb662db4108da6e6/pandas/core/generic.py#L9228) you will see that the `mask` is applied like a boolean filter, removing rows where the `mask` is `False`. So changing the `keep_equal` argument doesn't actually do anything when two `Series` are being compared. I have [logged](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49510) an issue in `pandas` documenting this.

## Extra stuff

- The `align_axis` parameter is basically a transpose of the results.
- The `result_names` allows you to change the names of the columns in the output (by default they are `"self"` and `"other"`).
- Comparing `DataFrame` instances operates in a similar manner, but the results will have a `MultiIndex` for the columns (level 0 is the name of the column, level 1 is the names in the `result_names` argument).